# IDE show classes independently

Tags: python, class, ide

So I'm fairly new in the coding world and I'm currently using PyCharm in developing a personal project.

This project has started to be somewhat "large" with many classes and I thought about splitting them up into module files like having MyClass in MyClass.py and use "from MyClass import *" in my main .py-file.

But I rather quickly realized that circular importing was a pain in the ass and that it was not really helping me in making the code more structured. I also found I could hide/collapse classes in my main file with the [-] which basically solved the bulk of my initial problem.

However, it got me thinking. I still liked the idea of visually having the classes in separate windows so I wondered if there's any IDE that actually do or allow this.

TL;DR: Is there an IDE which visually allow me to visually separate parts of code, like classes, in separate windows/pages, but still have them in the same py-file "physically"? Naturally with fully functional refactoring and code completion maintained.

Answer (score 0):

You can split PyCharm's window and open the same file in several tabs, viewing the part of the file you want in each. 
Open the file once, right click on the tab's title, then click Split Vertically / Horizontally.